# Comparator solution in generic methods

Tags: java, list, testing, junit, testcase

EDIT:

I edit comperator class to "IntegerComparator class" as mentioned earlier here.

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class IntegerComparator implements Comparator<Integer> {

public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
    if(o1>o2){
        return -1;
        }
        else if(o1<o2){
            return 1;
        }
    return 0;
  }
}
```

EDIT 2: Comparator Problem is solved! Look above.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your problem:

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Comparator<T> implements Comparator<? super T>
```

In the class file of `Comparator`, the word `Comparator` means itself, not the `java.util.Comparator` you imported. So, you're declaring a class that implements itself, which is obviously illegal.

The best approach, IMHO, to prevent any future confusion is to just rename your class:

```
import java.util.Comparator;

/* You can probably come up with a better name than this... */
public class MyComparator<T> implements Comparator<? super T>
```

Alternatively, if you really want to keep on calling your class `Comparator`, just make it implement the fully qualified `java.util.Comparator`:

```
public class Comparator<T> implements java.util.Comparator<? super T>
```

Comment: I renamed the class,so Eclipse asked if i can rename the .Java class which i admit. Now a new error comes:                      The type MyComparator cannot extend or implement Comparator<? super T>. A supertype may not specify any wildcard

Comment: arg, good point. Why do you need `super T` there? why not just implement `Comparator<T>`?

Comment: The type MyComparator<T> must implement the inherited abstract method Comparator<T>.compare(T, T)  so i have to add an unimplemented method compare, but i dont know how to fix the new one if i cant use Integer? Or make it Abstract, but why?

Comment: The Comparator<T> interface defines the `int compare(T o1, T o2);` method. That means that whatever type you are using for T will translate to the method as well. If you are defining  `MyComparator implements Comparator<Integer>`, you will be forced to implement `int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2);`. Try going through the generics introduction to better understand the concepts http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

Comment: Thanks. But do i Need Java.util.Comperator? Error is gone on class. Is Java.util needed?

Answer (score 1):

`Comparator` cannot implements itself. Change name of concrete class.

`IntegerComparator implements Comparator<Integer>`.